# no suitable conversion function from "orderedLinkedList<int>" to "const int" exists

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with a homework assignment and for the life of me I cannot figure out where I am making the mistake. We are tasked with writing a function that inserts the nodes of binary tree into an ordered linked list. Below are the header files and the main method. Literally any help at this point would greatly appreciated as I am just spinning in circles now.

Error Message: no suitable conversion function from "orderedLinkedList" to "const int" exists
Project: Ch19_Ex9 File: Ch19_Ex9.cpp Line: 33:

Ch19_Ex9.cpp:

```
//Data
//68 43 10 56 77 82 61 82 33 56 72 66 99 88 12 6 7 21 -999

#include "binarySearchTree.h"
#include "orderedLinkedList.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
binarySearchTree<int>  treeRoot;
orderedLinkedList<int> newList;

int num;

cout << "Enter numbers ending with -999" << endl;
cin >> num;

while (num != -999)
{
    treeRoot.insert(num);
    cin >> num;
}

cout << endl << "Tree nodes in inorder: ";
treeRoot.inorderTraversal();
cout << endl;
cout << "Tree Height: " << treeRoot.treeHeight()
    << endl;
treeRoot.createList(newList); //HERE IS THE LINE WITH ISSUE

cout << "newList: ";
newList.print();

cout << endl;
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

binarySearchTree.h:

```
//Header File Binary Search Tree

#include <iostream>
#include "binaryTree.h"

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class binarySearchTree : public binaryTreeType<Type>
{
public:
bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;
//Function to determine if searchItem is in the binary
//search tree.
//Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is found in
// the binary search tree; otherwise,
// returns false.

void insert(const Type& insertItem);
//Function to insert insertItem in the binary search tree.
//Postcondition: If there is no node in the binary search
// tree that has the same info as
// insertItem, a node with the info
// insertItem is created and inserted in the
// binary search tree.

void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
//Function to delete deleteItem from the binary search tree
//Postcondition: If a node with the same info as deleteItem
// is found, it is deleted from the binary
// search tree.
// If the binary tree is empty or deleteItem
// is not in the binary tree, an appropriate
// message is printed.

void createList(const Type& addItem);

 private:
void deleteFromTree(nodeType<Type>* &p);
//Function to delete the node to which p points is
//deleted from the binary search tree.
//Postcondition: The node to which p points is deleted
// from the binary search tree.
};


template <class Type>
bool binarySearchTree<Type>::search
(const Type& searchItem) const
{
nodeType<Type> *current;
bool found = false;

if (root == nullptrptr)
    cout << "Cannot search an empty tree." << endl;
else
{
    current = root;

    while (current != nullptrptr && !found)
    {
        if (current->info == searchItem)
            found = true;
        else if (current->info > searchItem)
            current = current->lLink;
        else
            current = current->rLink;
    }//end while
}//end else

return found;
}//end search

template <class Type>
void binarySearchTree<Type>::insert
(const Type& insertItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the node

newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
newNode->info = insertItem;
newNode->lLink = nullptrptr;
newNode->rLink = nullptrptr;

if (root == nullptrptr)
    root = newNode;
else
{
    current = root;

    while (current != nullptrptr)
    {
        trailCurrent = current;

        if (current->info == insertItem)
        {
            cout << "The item to be inserted is already ";
            cout << "in the tree -- duplicates are not "
                << "allowed." << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if (current->info > insertItem)
            current = current->lLink;
        else
            current = current->rLink;
    }//end while

    if (trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
        trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
    else
        trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;
}
}//end insert

template <class Type>
void binarySearchTree<Type>::deleteNode
(const Type& deleteItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
bool found = false;

if (root == nullptr)
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty tree."
    << endl;
else
{
    current = root;
    trailCurrent = root;

    while (current != nullptr && !found)
    {
        if (current->info == deleteItem)
            found = true;
        else
        {
            trailCurrent = current;

            if (current->info > deleteItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }
    }//end while

    if (current == nullptr)
        cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree."
        << endl;
    else if (found)
    {
        if (current == root)
            deleteFromTree(root);
        else if (trailCurrent->info > deleteItem)
            deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->lLink);
        else
            deleteFromTree(trailCurrent->rLink);
    }
    else
        cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the tree."
        << endl;
}
} //end deleteNode

template <class Type>
void binarySearchTree<Type>::deleteFromTree
(nodeType<Type>* &p)
{
nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the tree
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer behind current
nodeType<Type> *temp; //pointer to delete the node

if (p == nullptr)
    cout << "Error: The node to be deleted does not exist."
    << endl;
else if (p->lLink == nullptr && p->rLink == nullptr)
{
    temp = p;
    p = nullptr;
    delete temp;
}
else if (p->lLink == nullptr)
{
    temp = p;
    p = temp->rLink;
    delete temp;
}
else if (p->rLink == nullptr)
{
    temp = p;
    p = temp->lLink;
    delete temp;
}
else
{
    current = p->lLink;
    trailCurrent = nullptr;

    while (current->rLink != nullptr)
    {
        trailCurrent = current;
        current = current->rLink;
    }//end while

    p->info = current->info;

    if (trailCurrent == nullptr) //current did not move;
                                 //current == p->lLink; adjust p
        p->lLink = current->lLink;
    else
        trailCurrent->rLink = current->lLink;

    delete current;
}//end else
} //end deleteFromTree


template <class Type>
void binarySearchTree<Type>::createList(const Type& addItem) 
{
nodeType<Type> *current;
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
nodeType<Type> *newNode;

newNode = new nodeType <Type>;
newNode->info = createItem;
newNode->lLink = nullptr;
newNode->rLink = nullptr;

if (root == nullptr)
{
    root = newNode;
}

}
```

EDIT: adding orderedLinkedList.h:

```
 #include "linkedList.h"

 using namespace std;

 template <class Type>
 class orderedLinkedList : public linkedListType<Type>
 {
public:
bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;

void insert(const Type& newItem);

void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);

void insertLast(const Type& deleteItem);

void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
 };

 template <class Type>
 bool orderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) const
 {
nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
bool found = false;

current = first; //set current to point to the first 
                 //node in the list

while (current != nullptr && !found)    //search the list
    if (current->info == searchItem) //searchItem is found
        found = true;
    else
        current = current->link; //make current point to
                                 //the next node
return found;

};

template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{

};

template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

newNode->info = newItem;    //store the new item in the node
newNode->link = first;      //insert newNode before first
first = newNode;            //make first point to the
                            //actual first node
count++;                    //increment count

if (last == nullptr)   //if the list was empty, newNode is also 
                    //the last node in the list
    last = newNode;

};

template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& deleteItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node

newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the new node

newNode->info = newItem;  //store the new item in the node
newNode->link = nullptr;     //set the link field of newNode
                          //to nullptr

if (first == nullptr)  //if the list is empty, newNode is 
                    //both the first and last node
{
    first = newNode;
    last = newNode;
    count++;        //increment count
}
else    //the list is not empty, insert newNode after last
{
    last->link = newNode; //insert newNode after last
    last = newNode; //make last point to the actual 
                    //last node in the list
    count++;        //increment count
}

};

template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
nodeType<Type> *current;
nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
bool found;

if (first == nullptr)
{
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list."
    << endl;
}
else
{
    if (first->info == deleteItem)
    {
        current = first;
        first = first->link;
        count--;

        if (first == nullptr)
        {
            last = nullptr;

            delete current;
        }
        else
        {
            found = false;
            trailCurrent = first;

            current = first->link;

            while (current != nullptr && !found)
            {
                if (current->info != deleteItem)
                {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current->link;
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (found)
            {
                trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                count--;

                if (last == current)
                {
                    last = trailCurrent;
                }
                delete current;
            }
            else
                cout << "The item to be deleted is not in "
                << "the list." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: shouldn't `binarySearchTree::createList()` rather return a list it creates instead of taking a reference to a `const int`?

Comment: The main method was given to us, and we were asked now to change it. Based on how that was written I assumed it was taking a list rather than returning one?

Comment: I can tell from the error message that its getting caught up between the orderedLinkedList<int> and const int. My assumption is that I have written the createList method with the wrong parameter type, but I cant seem to figure out how to get it correctly. I tried updating the parameter type to orderedLinkedList<Type> but that didn't work either...

Comment: `orderedLinkedList<Type> &list` ... *didn't work* is no error message.

Comment: The update to orderedLinkList<type> &addItem gave me this error:
declaration is incompatible with "void binarySearchTree<Type>::createList(<error-type> &addItem)"

Comment: Did you include `orderedLinkedList.h`?

Comment: it has now been added.

Comment: You should `#include "orderedLinkedList.h"` in binarySearchTree.h

Comment: Hmmm, this is still not [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- something I can compile and help you with the problem. We need something compilable that reproduces the error. Allowing the compiler to help in your debugging with adequate warnings enabled dramatically reduces the debugging time. I see from `#include "pch.h"` you are likely using VS. You need at minimum `/W3` warnings enabled. If you don't have it already, add `/W3` to your compiler options in VS code or on the command line with the developer command prompt.